# Relative abundance of text string from IMG phylodist file

Tags: r

How do I use the text file below,

```
  gene_id                 homolog_gene_oid  homolog_taxon_oid percent_identity
1 Ga0197852_1000011       2656190422        2654587899            64.10
2 Ga0197852_1000012       2656190421        2654587899            91.96
3 Ga0197852_1000013       2656190420        2654587899            89.48

lineage
Hydrogenimonas thermophila_1
Hydrogenimonas thermophila_1
Hydrogenimonas thermophila_2
```

to create a relative abundance table (second column will sum to 1) of the genes (first column in file above) of each lineage (last column in file above), like below?

```
lineage                      rel_abund
Hydrogenimonas thermophila_1 0.66
Hydrogenimonas thermophila_2 0.33
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want the proportions of a factor/character vector, so you can wrap `table()` in `prop.table()`:

```
mydat <- read.table(text="gene_id       lineage homolog_gene_oid        homolog_taxon_oid       percent_identity
Ga0197852_1000011       thermophila_1   2656190422      2654587899      64.1
Ga0197852_1000012       thermophila_1   2656190421      2654587899      91.96
Ga0197852_1000013       thermophila_2   2656190420      2654587899      89.48
           ", header=T)

prop.table(table(mydat$lineage))
```

> ```
> thermophila_1 thermophila_2 
>     0.6666667     0.3333333
> ```

As a data.frame:

```
 as.data.frame(prop.table(table(mydat$lineage)))
```

> ```
>            Var1      Freq
> 1 thermophila_1 0.6666667
> 2 thermophila_2 0.3333333
> ```

Of course, you can name the columns whatever you like using `names()` or `colnames()`.

```
rel_abundance <- as.data.frame(prop.table(table(mydat$lineage)))
names(rel_abundance) <- c("Lineage", "Rel. Abundance")
rel_abundance
```

> ```
>         Lineage     Rel. Abundance
> 1 thermophila_1      0.6666667
> 2 thermophila_2      0.3333333
> ```

Note that I left off the word "Hydrogenimonas" in the `lineage` just because of how I had to parse your data without a spreadsheet app to help me (for this reason we encourage the use of `dput()`, built-in data sets, or data sets created within the code of your question).